# Does ASLR protect against a buffer overflow within a struct?

Tags: buffer-overflow, aslr

Assume a simple struct:

```
struct test {
   char variable[4];
   char variable2;
}
```

If I write something like `variable[4] = '\0'` there is a buffer overflow which modifies variable2.

Does ASLR prevent this buffer overflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASLR never prevents any buffer overflow. A buffer overflow is when the application writes more bytes in a buffer than can possibly fit; putting the buffer at any random address cannot fix that.

What ASLR changes is the *consequences* of the overflow. A buffer overflow is exploited by an attacker by trying to making the extra bytes spill over some other elements in a controlled way. ASLR makes that more difficult in two ways:

- By "moving things around", the field that the attacker tries to overwrite will not necessarily be located at a predictable place beyond the overflowing buffer.
- A classic overflow exploit is about overwriting a jump field (return address on the stack, vtable for a C++ object...) so that execution jumps elsewhere; ASLR tries to force a blind jump which is unlikely to go anywhere interesting (for the attacker).

In the case of a `struct`, ASLR will not separate the two structure fields, because that would be contrary to the C specification, and it would break code. Regardless of ASLR, the `variable2` field will always be right after the `variable` buffer in RAM, so the buffer overflow will predictably overwrite `variable2`. However, ASLR still moves code chunks between two executions of the application, so overwriting `variable2` might not be sufficient to, say, inject arbitrary code.